# PHP scandir limit of files number

Tags: php, file, count, scandir

I have a folder in my webserver that contains 81633 files in. I can see that by using the command: `ls | wc -l`

When I use scandir function it returns me only 80476 files :

```
$files = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets/doc/bons/");
echo count($files);
```

The same result with :

```
$d = new DirectoryIterator($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
$cnt = 0;
foreach($d as $fileinfo) {
      $cnt++;
}
echo $cnt;
```

result: 80476 files

All files have the same permissions.
Is there some kind on limitation on PHP side or on file system side?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls | wc -l` is not the right way to count files.

[This is how to count files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23130/how-to-report-number-of-files-in-all-subdirectories?lq=1).

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113463/use-of-ls-with-wc-command

Comment: Ok thanks. So with the right method I have 81645 (a cron job has copied some more files) files but still 80476 with PHP.

Comment: My bad... the problem was the wrong path I used.

Comment: I wouldn't criticize the use of `ls | wc -l` as it correctly counts the files in a dir basically always.. and for sure it's much more convenient that using a `for loop`. I guess you never had `\n` char in a filename too, although it's possible :) also, my version of `ls` displays it in a single line `'foo'$'\n''bar'`